# activating a text field on <cr> input

Tags: textfield, codenameone

Trying to get codename1 textfields to activate when a newline is
entered, the best I've done is to define this in a textfield 
subclass

```
public void keyPressed(int keycode)
{   
    if(keycode==-90) // where does this number come from?
    { fireDoneEvent(); 
    } 
}
```

Where does this mysterious constant "-90" come from.
Is there a better supported way to do this?

Comment: Please can you give more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve ? and what do you mean by 'activate'?  (is it something that you tap on it and get focus or you're referring to something else)

Comment: I want to send "done" to listeners.  That's what fireDoneEvent does.  The effect I want is that you type a message and it gets processed when you type a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Key pressed will only be invoked in a physical keyboard and not on virtual keyboard so you are in a completely wrong direction. If this is a multiline text field you can easily recognize the newline with `\n` using the `DataChangeListener` if this is a single line text field you should use the done listener which will only work on the device (with the VKB).

Comment: I am using "done" listeners, but it seems to take two <cr> to get an event,  I would guess one to terminate native editing and one to get codename1's attention.

Comment: It should work instantly with the done listener as it is implemented natively. Are you using a virtual keyboard?

Comment: yes, standard tablet/phone keyboards.  I'll try to collect more data the next time I see this.